# Spring Security SAML and Pringfederate

Tags: security, saml, pingfederate

I configured our App with PingFederate as the SSO server. I configured an SP and an Adapter.

The App is Grails based application, which is based on Spring Security SAML. With the debugging, I saw Assert comes back from PingFederate successfully. Also, the signature is verified. However, looks like the certificate from Ping is not being trusted:

Here is the log:

```
2018-02-15 09:04:26,805 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine  - Attempting to verify signature using trusted credentials
2018-02-15 09:04:26,805 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine  - Failed to verify signature using either KeyInfo-derived or directly trusted credentials
2018-02-15 09:04:26,816 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller  - Starting to marshall {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature
2018-02-15 09:04:26,816 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller  - Creating XMLSignature object
2018-02-15 09:04:26,817 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller  - Adding content to XMLSignature.
2018-02-15 09:04:26,817 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller  - Creating Signature DOM element
2018-02-15 09:04:28,531 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller  - Starting to unmarshall Apache XML-Security-based SignatureImpl element
2018-02-15 09:04:28,531 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller  - Constructing Apache XMLSignature object
2018-02-15 09:04:28,532 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller  - Adding canonicalization and signing algorithms, and HMAC output length to Signature
2018-02-15 09:04:28,532 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller  - Adding KeyInfo to Signature
2018-02-15 09:04:32,498 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine  - Attempting to verify signature and establish trust using KeyInfo-derived credentials
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52801', transport: 'socket'
2018-02-15 09:04:32,506 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine  - Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
2018-02-15 09:04:32,506 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine  - Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
2018-02-15 09:04:32,506 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine  - Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
2018-02-15 09:04:32,507 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine  - Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
2018-02-15 09:04:32,507 [ : http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine  - Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554673/spring-saml-handshake-failure-failed-to-validate-untrusted-credential-against

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring SAML handshake failure - Failed to validate untrusted credential against trusted key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554673/spring-saml-handshake-failure-failed-to-validate-untrusted-credential-against)